# why did i lose the functionality of my third-party driver in the updated version even after reinstalling the driver?

Tags: apt, kernel, additional-drivers

In synaptic i find an installed kernel version ...> 4.15.0-**139.143** (what is that weird version that dot?) but i can't find such version in apt-get.
the problem is the new updated kernel (4.15.0-140-generic) doesn't support a third party wifi driver https://github.com/mattousamine/animated-lamp which was working fine at 4.15.0-**139.143**
.i tried to mark the kernel,headers,and modules of the previously installed kernel,but it was no good.

so,is there any way to make the wifi driver work for the current updated kernel (4.15.0-140-generic)? or to save the previous kernel markings in synaptic(i saved the full state,but i think there is a better way)?

[the kernel,headers,and modules version in synaptic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyip.png)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: thanks @KGIII  it seems i misunderstood  the **make** command,i thought it would force overwrite the compilation of the previous kernel,fortunately by chance i tried "clean" and saw multiple **rm**,thought maybe i need to recompile,and voilà it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to clean(since make doesn't overwrite) the directory before the recompilation process for the new kernel with:

```
make clean
```

then proceed as usual

```
make

sudo make install
```